# Change width and height of a gridhelper in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

[Gridhelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/helpers/GridHelper) seems to only have size which makes it square. Can't it be a rectangle where I can define a width and a height or maybe there's another way for me to do that in three.js? I think it might have 'scale' but that will make the divisions warp.

```
var size = 50;
var divisions = 10;

var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
scene.add(gridHelper);
```

Comment: You can change the index of a plane buffer geometry (see this related [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/grids-of-waves-shaders/1168?u=prisoner849) and its jsfiddle, pay attention to the `.toGrid()` method), or feel free to write your own grid helper, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/helpers/GridHelper.js) of the existing one.

Comment: @foreyes yeah, there's always a ready-to-use solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution at bocoup: https://bocoup.com/blog/learning-three-js-with-real-world-challenges-that-have-already-been-solved

```
function createAGrid(opts) {
  var config = opts || {
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    linesHeight: 10,
    linesWidth: 10,
    color: 0xDD006C
  };

  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: config.color,
    opacity: 0.2
  });

  var gridObject = new THREE.Object3D(),
    gridGeo = new THREE.Geometry(),
    stepw = 2 * config.width / config.linesWidth,
    steph = 2 * config.height / config.linesHeight;

  //width
  for (var i = -config.width; i <= config.width; i += stepw) {
    gridGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-config.height, i, 0));
    gridGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(config.height, i, 0));

  }
  //height
  for (var i = -config.height; i <= config.height; i += steph) {
    gridGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, -config.width, 0));
    gridGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, config.width, 0));
  }

  var line = new THREE.Line(gridGeo, material, THREE.LinePieces);
  gridObject.add(line);

  return gridObject;
}
```

But had to change

```
var line = new THREE.Line(gridGeo, material, THREE.LinePieces);
```

(deprecated) to

```
var line = new THREE.LineSegments(gridGeo, material);
```

Comment: The function creates an object twice bigger than it has to. Stepw and Steph multiplied by 2 for no reason, as well as vertices are put at -config.height and config.height (as well as -config.width and config.width) which is twice bigger than an actual object should be.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution that Shai UI has provided and some of the codes are already deprecated.

I'm currently using the latest version of Three.js (r155). Here's what worked for me:

```
function createAGrid(opts) {
    var config = opts || {
        height: 60,
        width: 30,
        linesHeight: 60,
        linesWidth: 30,
        color: 0x000000
    };

    const points = [];

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: config.color,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.2
    });

    var gridObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    var stepw = 2 * config.width / config.linesWidth;
    var steph = 2 * config.height / config.linesHeight;

    // Add horizontal lines
    for (var i = -config.height; i <= config.height; i += steph) {
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-config.width, i, 0));
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(config.width, i, 0));
    }

    // Add vertical lines
    for (var i = -config.width; i <= config.width; i += stepw) {
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, -config.height, 0));
        points.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, config.height, 0));
    }

    var gridGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments(gridGeo, material);

    gridObject.add(line);
    scene.add(gridObject);

}
```